# Image non displaying in React Native application: URI source with local path

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show an image inside a React Native app, but I am experiencing some issues. 
Considering that the runtime value of `this.state.icon` is `'./icons/Icon.png'`, I can't figure out why the first line of code doesn't work (an empty blank space is shown instead of the image), while the second version works properly.

```
<Image style={styles.Icon} source={this.state.icon} />

<Image style={styles.Icon} source={require('./icons/Icon.png')} />
```

This kind of solution doesn't work too:
    source={{uri: './icons/Icon.png'}}

Answer (score 1):

require does not support dynamic loading of modules. Javascript files are statically analysed. See Similar issue athttps://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481

Comment: it would only work if this.state.icon is the result of require('./icons/carIcon.png'). but the string inside the require has to be a literal in your javascript code